# What does the Uri returned from the contact picker actually point to?

Tags: android

I am trying to select a phone number from the contacts list.  Everything is working fine, but I am storing the phone number.  I would like to store a pointer to the phone number so that if it is changed I get the new number.

I think I should just store the Uri that I get back in onActivityResult,  but I am not sure exactly what that points to.

The [doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/contacts-provider.html#Access) says startActivityForResult() *"returns the content URI of the selected row. The form of the URI is the table's content URI with the row's LOOKUP_ID appended to it."*

Can anyone point me to a doc, or explain what this Uri is? 
Is a better way to store the pointer to the phone number, other than storing this uri and then going through the query again?

BTW,  I may just store both and implement a listener on the contacts database and only re-query if the database has been updated.

I pick the contact using the contact picker as such;

```
Intent pickContactIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
pickContactIntent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_TYPE);
startActivityForResult(pickContactIntent, PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST);
```

Then after picking it I get the phone number using something like this:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {            
    if (requestCode == PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST) {
        if (resultCode == android.app.Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Uri contactUri = data.getData();
            Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(contactUri,null, null, null, null);
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                int columnPhone = cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER);
                String number = cursor.getString(columnPhone);
            }
        }   
    }
}
```